# multipart/form-data upload Task doesn't call Authentication Challenge for large files in iOS

Tags: swift, azure, iis

I'm trying to upload a zip file from mobile to a remote Azure server using `URLSession.dataTask(with: r as URLRequest)`. For that, I'm using `NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust` & `NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate` authentication. The two works fine when the size of zip file is ~15KB.

But for bigger files, I only see `NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust` and then the requested times out. I've already spent 3 days without any concrete direction on this.

```
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {

    if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate{
        if useFirstCert, let certURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "azure-client1-cert", withExtension: "p12"){
            let cred = credential(from: certURL, password: "passcode")
            completionHandler(URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.useCredential, cred)
        }else {
            completionHandler(URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.cancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil)
        }
    }else if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust{
        completionHandler(URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.rejectProtectionSpace, nil)
    }else{
        completionHandler(URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.performDefaultHandling, nil);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got a response from Microsoft as following blogpost - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2017/04/03/posting-a-large-file-can-fail-if-you-enable-client-certificates/

I’ve just had a successful certificate upload in a prototype app with a 124K file. All needs to be done is to Set the Expect: 100-continue header for the request.

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url)
request.setValue("100-continue", forHTTPHeaderField: "Expect")
```

It's applicable for all protocols using IIS.